# Writing a log-likelihood with the apply family of functions. Perfomance loss?

Tags: r

I'm playing around with apply() family of functions in R, and was trying to write a log-likelihood function using apply().

Here's the log-likelihood for a linear regression model assuming gaussian disturbances:

```
# Likelihood function for the standard linear regression model

logL <- function(theta, data){
    # Return minus the log likelihood function for the standard linear regression model
    # y: endogenous variable
    # x: matrix of regressors
    y <- data[, 1]
    x <- data[, -1]
    N <- nrow(data)
    # This is the contribution to the log-likelihood of individual i. Initialized at 0.
    contrib <- 0
    beta <- head(theta, -1) # Every element but the last one
    sigma <- tail(theta, 1) # Only the last element
    for (i in 1:N){
        contrib <- contrib + (y[i] - beta%*%x[i,])**2
    }
    sigma <- abs(sigma)
    L <- -(1/(2*sigma^2)*contrib) - 1/2 * N * log(2*pi) - N * log(sigma)
    return(-L)
}
```

And below we simulate some data and minimize the negative log-likelihood (which is equivalent to maximising the log-likelihood).

```
# Simulate some data
N <- 1000
x <- cbind(1, rnorm(N,0,sd=1), rnorm(N, 0, sd=2)) 

true_theta <- c(2, 3, 2, 4)

y <- true_theta[1:3]%*%t(x) + rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = true_theta[4])

my_data <- cbind(t(y),x)

optim(c(1,1,1, 1), fn = logL, data = my_data, 
method = "L-BFGS-B",upper = c(Inf, Inf, Inf), lower=c(-Inf, -Inf, 0.01))
```

So far so good, we get the same results as those used to simulate the data. By using the rbenchmark package I get that 10 replications of the optimization step takes around 4 seconds on my computer.

```
benchmark(optim(c(1,1,1, 1), fn = logL, data = my_data,
method = "L-BFGS-B",upper = c(Inf, Inf, Inf), lower=c(-Inf, -Inf, 0.01)),
replications=10)
```

Now I tried replacing the for-loop with the apply function. For this, I defined contrib to be a function:

```
contrib <- function(beta, one_obs){
    y <- one_obs[1]
    x <- one_obs[-1]
    return((y - beta%*%x)**2)
}
```

And the new log-likelihood function:

```
logL2 <- function(theta, data){
# Return minus the log likelihood function for the standard linear   regression model
# y: endogenous variable
# x: matrix of regressors
N <- nrow(data)
beta <- head(theta, -1) # Every element but the last one
sigma <- tail(theta, 1) # Only the last element
sigma <- abs(sigma)
L <- -(1/(2*sigma^2)*sum(apply(data, FUN=contrib, beta = beta, 1))) 
- 1/2 * N * log(2*pi) - N * log(sigma)
return(-L)
}
```

This is almost twice as long. Now, I may have misunderstood the role of the apply family of functions, as they should be used for code clarity rather than for performance. However, they shouldn't be slower than a for loop, right? So what is happening with my code? Is some type conversion going on? I checked and logL returns a matrix and logL2 returns a numeric. I tried using vapply() as it allows to specify the type of the object returned, but vapply() seems to convert my data matrix into a vector by stacking every column on top of each other. This causes the contrib function not to work anymore:

```
logL2 <- function(theta, data){
# Return minus the log likelihood function for the standard linear regression model
# y: endogenous variable
# x: matrix of regressors
N <- nrow(data)
beta <- head(theta, -1) # Every element but the last one
sigma <- tail(theta, 1) # Only the last element
sigma <- abs(sigma)
L <- -(1/(2*sigma^2)*sum(vapply(data, FUN=contrib, beta = beta, FUN.VALUE = matrix(1)))) - 1/2 * N * log(2*pi) - N * log(sigma)
return(-L)
}
```

This is what I get then:

```
class(logL2(theta = c(1,2,2,2), my_data))

Error in beta %*% x : non-conformable arguments
```

So how could I use the apply family of functions to make my code more readable, and at least as fast as with a for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your code by thinking about the maths involved in your for loop.

Your for loop is

```
contrib <- contrib + (y[i] - beta%*%x[i,])**2
```

Now this is the same as just calculating all the `(y[i] - beta %*% x[i, ])^2` and summing them all. Thinking about `beta %*% x[i, ]` you are doing matrix multiplication of a 1x3 matrix (`beta`) with a 3x1 (`x[i, ]`), giving a 1x1 result. So what you are doing is matrix-multiplying `beta` by *each row* of `x` independently.
However, with matrix multiplication you can do them all simultaneously anyway, and get a Nx1 matrix out!

i.e. `beta` (1x3) `%*%` `x` (3xN) would give you a 1xN matrix, and then subtract this from `y` which is also a vector of length N, square each difference independently and sum them. This is equivalent to your for loop.

The only catch is that your `x` is Nx3 not 3xN, so we `t()` it first:

```
contrib <- sum((y - beta %*% t(x))^2)
```

This does away with your for loop entirely.

```
logL2 <- function(theta, data){
    y <- data[, 1]
    x <- data[, -1]
    N <- nrow(data)
    beta <- head(theta, -1) # Every element but the last one
    sigma <- tail(theta, 1) # Only the last element
    contrib <- sum((y - beta %*% t(x))^2)
    sigma <- abs(sigma)
    L <- -(1/(2*sigma^2)*contrib) - 1/2 * N * log(2*pi) - N * log(sigma)
    return(-L)
}

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(
    orig={orig.answer <- optim(c(1,1,1, 1), fn = logL, data = my_data,
method = "L-BFGS-B",upper = c(Inf, Inf, Inf), lower=c(-Inf, -Inf, 0.01))},
    new={new.answer <- optim(c(1,1,1, 1), fn = logL2, data = my_data,
method = "L-BFGS-B",upper = c(Inf, Inf, Inf), lower=c(-Inf, -Inf, 0.01))},
replications=10
)
```

which yields

```
  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2  new           10   0.306     1.00     0.332    0.048          0         0
1 orig           10   4.584    14.98     4.588    0.000          0         0
```

and also let's just check we didn't make a mistake

```
all.equal(orig.answer, new.answer)
# [1] TRUE
```

As a style point, why not have `y` being a third argument to `logL2` (rather than `cbind`ing it to `data` at the start, and then having to select the appropriate row/columns all the time)? This saves you from doing the `y <- data[, 1]` and `x <- data[, -1]` all the time. I.e. do something like `logL <- function (theta, x, y) { ... }` and then in your `optim()` call you can provide the `x` and `y` arguments rather than `my_data`. You might even get a further improvement by doing `t(x)` at the very start (e.g. in your call to optim) so it doesn't have to be done every time `logL2` is called?

```
logL3 <- function(theta, x, y){
  N <- length(y)
  beta <- head(theta, -1) # Every element but the last one
  sigma <- tail(theta, 1) # Only the last element
  contrib <- sum((y - beta %*% x)^2)
  sigma <- abs(sigma)
  L <- -(1/(2*sigma^2)*contrib) - 1/2 * N * log(2*pi) - N * log(sigma)
  return(-L)
}

benchmark(
  new=optim(c(1,1,1, 1), fn = logL2, data = my_data,
            method = "L-BFGS-B",upper = c(Inf, Inf, Inf), lower=c(-Inf, -Inf, 0.01)),
  new.new=optim(c(1,1,1, 1), fn = logL3, x=t(x), y=y,
            method = "L-BFGS-B",upper = c(Inf, Inf, Inf), lower=c(-Inf, -Inf, 0.01)),
  replications=100
)
     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1     new          100   3.149    2.006     3.317    0.700          0         0
2 new.new          100   1.570    1.000     1.488    0.344          0         0
```

It's about twice as fast. In general, if you can do something once rather than every time `logL2` is called (e.g. `t(x)`, `data[, 1]` etc) it'll save you some small amount of time.

---

With respect to your original question however (specifically to do with the `*apply` functions:

- `vapply` takes a *list* as input, and your `data` is a matrix, so `contrib` is operating on one element of `data` at a time. I.e. `contrib` sees `x` as a single number. Hence nonconformable matrices, since your matrix multiplication is multiplying `beta` (a 1x3) with `x` (a 1x1) and for matrix multiplication to work, you need the number of columns of `beta` to equal the number of rows of `x`. To use `vapply` you'd need something like

  ```
  vapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) contrib(beta, data[i, ]), FUN.VALUE=1)
  ```
- (! I have not tested these statements by benchmarking or anything. This is just what I have found in my experience): of all the `*apply` functions, I find that `apply()` is slow (often slower than the for-loop). It is handy for neatness of code ("do this for every row", or "do this for every column"-type tasks: instead of lots of `data[i, ]` it's just `apply(.., MARGIN=1)`), but if you need speed do a for loop or use one of the other cousins like `vapply`, `lapply` or `sapply`.
- `vapply`, `lapply` are fast. `sapply` is too, but in general one of the former two is faster (`sapply` is easier to use due to the `FUN.VALUE` bit of `vapply` being worked out for you. Or if you know that the `FUN.VALUE` won't always be the same, it is equivalent to `lapply` so you may as well use that. Since `sapply` does all this working out for you it can be easier to use, but minutely slower).
- fastest of all is if you can use some maths to avoid a loop! e.g. if you can rephrase your loop in terms of a matrix multiplication as I did here. Though this only applies to a very small number of situations.

Comment: Welcome back, MC. Great answer.

Comment: Matrix Multiplication in R is very fast which is implemented by c/fortran and we even can build R with openBLAS, Intel MKL, cuBLAS to leverage multi-cores power, [here](http://www.cybaea.net/Blogs/Faster-R-through-better-BLAS.html) :) Very great answer @mathematical.coffee, up.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the very detailed answer! It is true that I can get rid of the loop in this particular case, but my goal was to compare for loops and apply (hence the for loop instead of using matrix multiplication). It would seem then that in cases were you cannot do otherwise than use a loop, there's no real way to make it faster (apart from parallelization, maybe, but this is not always trivial). Thanks also for all the other tips to make the code run faster!